# Is there any Wedding Album Designing Software for ubuntu like Karizma Albums in windows?

Tags: photography

I use Karizma Albums ( http://www.karizmaalbums.com/ ) in windows for filpbook type wedding album designing.
Is there any equivalent programs for ubuntu?
I would prefer open source and free softwares first.
Any suggestion would be of great help.
Thanks in advance.

I found Scribus (  http://www.scribus.net  )is somewhat useful for doing this type of work, but I am not accustomed to Scribus, and testing it for album designing. Still if you have any suggestion or tutorial link to Scribus specific to this type of album designing, please mention.

Comment: Did you try to run Karizma Albums under Wine?

Comment: No. Its almost 15GB, but I'm sure even if it works, it would not function properly and more important natively. The way to access Linux directories of wine loaded programs are always difficult to manage.

Comment: No, sorry it does not run under wine. No hope..